# timeseries data plot from sqlite database with gnuplot

Tags: bash, sqlite, plot, time-series, gnuplot

Can I plot directly time-series dataset with gnuplot from sqlite database?

I have an sqlite db, I would like to plot time series data. I created the query. Really simple it's working. This is the sqlite3 query, and sending to a file:

```
$ sqlite3 ./home_temp.db "SELECT datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch'), ROUND(temperature, 2) FROM bme280_data ORDER BY datetime_int DESC LIMIT 288;" >> home_temp.dat
```

This is few line from the home_temp.dat file:

```
2020-10-12 13:20:01|21.02
2020-10-12 13:15:02|20.95
2020-10-12 13:10:01|20.89
2020-10-12 13:05:01|20.8
2020-10-12 13:00:01|20.74
2020-10-12 12:55:02|20.87
```

I can read this with gnuplot, and plot it. That's ok.

```
#! /usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal dumb 150 25
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xtics rotate by -90
set datafile separator "|"

plot  "<(sqlite3 ./home_temp.db 'SELECT datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch'), ROUND(temperature, 2) FROM bme280_data ORDER BY datetime_int DESC LIMIT 288;')" using 1:2 with lines

plot './home_temp.dat' using 1:2 with lines
pause -1
```

Now, when I change this the gnuplot file, to read from sqlitedb, not from file. It's not working anymore. Anybody has any idea why?

```
#! /usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal dumb 150 25
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xtics rotate by -90
set datafile separator "|"

SqliteField(f) = '< sqlite3 ./home_temp.db "SELECT '.f.' FROM bme280_data ORDER BY datetime_int DESC LIMIT 288;"' 

fields = "datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch'), ROUND(temperature, 2)"

plot for [f in fields] SqliteField(f) using 1:2 with lines
```

Error message: `x range is invalid`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Point:

There seems to be a misunderstanding in your code about the use of '[f in fields]'. In the "plot for" loop of your code, the loop body is executed three times, with the following values sequentially assigned to 'f'.

```
datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch’)
ROUND(temperature
2)
```

This is because the string stored in fields is splitted by whitespace character and passed to f sequentially.

If you don't use the loop and simply evaluate "SqliteField(fields)", I think you will get the result you want.

#### Second Point:

In the definition of SqliteField(f), you don't need the trailing double quotation mark. You can check the result string of SqliteField(fields) by simply printing it to STDOUT,

```
print SqliteField(fields)
```

#### Summary

Your code would work if it were modified as follows.

```
#! /usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal dumb 150 25
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xtics rotate by -90
set datafile separator "|"

SqliteField(f) = '< sqlite3 ./home_temp.db "SELECT '.f.' FROM bme280_data ORDER BY datetime_int DESC LIMIT 288;' 

fields = "datetime(datetime_int,'unixepoch'), ROUND(temperature, 2)"

plot SqliteField(fields) using 1:2 with lines
```